# What is an analytical definition or $\epsilon-\Bbb N$ definition for a sequence in real numbers which doesn't have any convergence subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, compactness

I have one conceptual question: what is an analytical definition or $\epsilon-\Bbb N$ definition for a sequence in real numbers which doesn't have any convergence subsequence.

I was thinking in this way that $\not \exists$ any subsequence $(x_{n_i})$ s.t $x_{n_i} \not \to L$ so for any increasing sequence $(n_i)$ there exist $\epsilon >0$ s.t for all $N \in \Bbb N$ there is a $m,n>N$ s.t $|x_m-x_n|>\epsilon$.

My question is to make the definition smoother. So that I can see this more easily what I am observing is that the sequence has to be unbounded. Can I say that there exists $\epsilon>0$ s.t $|x_n-x_m|>\epsilon$ for all but finitely many $m,n \in \Bbb N$? Please help with your idea.

I also invite to have your answer about how do you write the definition of a sequence in real numbers which doesn't have any convergence subsequence.

**Further edit:**

1. Another idea that came to my mind is that there is an $\epsilon>0$
   s.t there is $N \in \Bbb N$ so that for all $k \in \Bbb N$ we have
   $|x_N-x_{N+k}|\geq \epsilon$.

If statement 1 holds then the sequence can't have a convergent subsequence.
If statement 1 doesn't hold then for any $\epsilon>0$ and for any $N \in \Bbb N$ there exist $k \in \Bbb N$ s.t $|x_{N+k}-x_N|<\epsilon$ and then we will start with $x_1$ and $ \epsilon=1$ then we will get $x_{1+k_1}$ then $x_{1+k_1+k_2}$ for $\epsilon=\frac 12$ and proceed in this way to get a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Starting point: this is equivalent to every subsequence being unbounded (if it has a bounded subsequence, then that sequence has a convergent subsequence). Which sequences have no bounded subsequences?

Comment: Note that your last suggestion doesn't work: for example, the sequence $0,0,1,2,3,4,...$ has no convergent subsequence, but no such $\varepsilon$ exists.

Comment: @user3482749 Yes true. My second assumption fails. I changed it to "for all but finitely many $m,n$." For your first question strictly increasing or decreasing unbounded sequences don't have any convergent subsequences but I am struggling with getting iff condition.

Comment: @Ri-Li Strictly increasing/decreasing sequences aren't the only ones with no bounded subsequences, but there aren't that many more... (consider $|x_n|$)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut No, I'm attempting to talk the OP to the solution. In particular, $|x_n| \to \infty$, and that is a necessary and sufficient condition (it is exactly the statement that only finitely many terms lie in any interval of the form $(-C,C)$, so is implied by your condition, and also implies that condition, as such intervals contain all bounded intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has no convergent subsequence; then $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n=x\}$ is finite for each $x\in\Bbb R$, and $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is infinite. Suppose that $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$. Then there is a sequence $\tau$ in $A\setminus\{x\}$ converging to $x$, and it’s not hard to show that $\tau$ has a subsequence $\tau'$ that is also a subsequence of $\sigma$. This is impossible, so $A$ has no accumulation points and is therefore a closed, discrete subset of $\Bbb R$.

It would be nice if this meant that there were an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|x_n-x_m|\ge\epsilon$ for all $n,m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\ne x_m$, but this is not necessarily the case. Let $x_0=0$, and for $n>0$ let $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$, the $n$-th harmonic number $H_n$. Then $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is strictly increasing, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$, so $\sigma$ has no convergent subsequence. However, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1n<\epsilon$, so that

$$|x_{k+1}-x_k|=\frac1{k+1}<\frac1n<\epsilon$$

whenever $k\ge n$.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, you discarded my second suggestion with an excellent example. I also wanted an $\epsilon-\Bbb N$ definition of the sequence having no convergent subsequence and hence you are saying that for each $x_n$ there is $\epsilon >0$ s.t $A \cap B(x_n,\epsilon)=\{x_n\}$. Have I understood it correctly? I have also edited(added) one statement. Please check it if possible.

Comment: @Ri-Li: Consider the sequence $x_n=\frac1{2^n}$: for each $n$ there’s an $\epsilon>0$ such that $A\cap B(x_n,\epsilon)=\{x_n\}$, but the sequence itself is convergent. In fact, your condition here is satisfied by any sequence of distinct points. What you need is that for each $x\in\Bbb R$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $A\cap B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq\{x\}$. (I’ll take a look at your update in a bit.)

Comment: @Ri-Li: The property in your update is satisfied by all convergent sequences of distinct points. Let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be such a sequence. If $\sigma\to x_0$, let $N=1$, and otherwise let $N=0$. Let $\epsilon=\inf\{|x_n-x_N|:n>N\}>0$. Then $|x_N-x_{N+k}|\ge\epsilon$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z^+$.